# Print List of Lists without brackets

Tags: haskell

I am trying to print Pascals triangle up to some arbitrary row, after some thought I came up with this solution:

```
next xs = zipWith (+) ([0] ++ xs) (xs ++ [0])
pascal n = take n (iterate next [1])

main = do
   n <- readLn :: IO Int
   mapM_ putStrLn $ map show $ pascal n
```

Which works quite well, except for the printing. When I apply `pascal 4` I get:

```
[1]
[1,1]
[1,2,1]
[1,3,3,1]
```

When what I really want is this:

```
1
1 1
1 2 1
1 3 3 1
```

Is there any way I can do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Define your own pretty-printing function:

```
import Data.List (intercalate)

show' :: Show a => [a] -> String
show' = intercalate " " . map show
```

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Ill mark as the answer when able.

Answer (score 6):

You could unwords / unlines:

```
import Data.List
...
putStr $ unlines $ map (unwords . map show) $ pascal n
```